# What Android device should I buy for Android app development?

Tags: android

I'm in the market for a basic Android device.  My main reason for buying one is for learning to develop mobile apps.  While the Eclipse IDE offers a virtual Android device for testing apps, it's not the same thing as a real Android device and won't put me on the same wavelength as Android device users.  (The most obvious example: Visibility is poorer in a bright outdoor environment than indoors.)

Some questions:

1. Is a tablet PC the type of device I should get?  I get the impression that it's more versatile than other devices.  I don't need a smartphone, because my dumbphone works well for me, and I don't even use it that much.  And I HATE the idea of being locked into a specific wireless provider.  I'm not interested in ebooks, because I still like books on paper better.
2. Should I get a device with Android 2.3 or 4.0?  On the one hand, over 90% of current Android users are using version 2.3.3 or earlier.  On the other hand, 4.0 is better and will be gaining market share.  (Would buying an Android 2.3 device now and buying an Android 4.0 device later be my best bet?)
3. In addition to wifi, what else should I look for?
4. Are there any brands/models I should avoid?  I remember hearing that the Packard Bell PCs were the most unreliable.  The Yugo was a terrible value.  (An old Oldsmobile Cutlass clunker was a better value - at least as reliable but MUCH cheaper to buy.)
5. Is there any point in buying used?  The listings on Ebay and Google Shopping don't show the used tablet PCs to be that much cheaper than new ones, and there are more new tablets than used ones available.

Ebay listings currently (5-23-2012) show over 200 Android 2.3 tablets selling for $55-$90:
http://www.ebay.com/sch/iPads-Tablets-eBook-Readers-/171485/i.html?Operating%2520System=Android%25202%252E3%252Ex%2520Gingerbread&LH_BIN=1&Internet%2520Connectivity=Wi%252DFi%7CWi%252DFi%2520%252B%25203G%7CWi%252DFi%2520%252B%25204G&_nkw=android+2.3&_dmpt=US_Tablets&rt=nc&LH_ItemCondition=1000

Ebay listings currently (5-23-2012) show over 200 Android 4.0 tablets selling for $83-$107:
http://www.ebay.com/sch/iPads-Tablets-eBook-Readers-/171485/i.html?Operating%2520System=Android%25204%252Ex%2520Ice%2520Cream%2520Sandwich&LH_BIN=1&LH_ItemCondition=1000&Type=Tablet&_pppn=r1&_dmpt=US_Tablets&Internet%2520Connectivity=Wi%252DFi%7CWi%252DFi%2520%252B%25203G%7CWi%252DFi%2520%252B%25204G

What do you think?

Comment: My development platform is Linux, so I'm not concerned about compatibility with Windows.  I hate Windows, and the bad reviews of Vista made me determined to never buy Windows again.
Given that most Android users are using version 2.3.3 or earlier, I'm getting an Android 2.3 device for now.

Comment: What advantages does a smartphone have over a tablet if I'm not going to make/receive calls on it?  Since I already have a dumbphone, and I'm not even fully utilizing it, I'm still leaning towards a tablet over a smartphone.  Wouldn't it be better for me to buy one of the cheaper tablets now and then buy a smartphone sometime later?

Answer (score 5):

This question is probably off topic.

But here are my thoughts:

If you want to develop the truth is you should try to have access (be it ownership or just access) to any devices that you intend to support with your applications. This is certainly not possible for everyone, but there are ways that you can maximize your value while building a device collection by aiming to hit the largest swath of different types of devices.

You have no obligation to be locked into a contract (or even any service) for a telephone. If you go to a carrier store you can purchase a device at full price and leave the store without activating any service on it (In general, subject to change at the whim of whatever store you are in =) If you intend to by a phone for full price expect the range of prices to be $380-$600. From what I can tell about your situation I would think that a phone is best route for you to start off with. In addition to being able to buy from a carrier, Google also from time to time directly sells a "Nexus" device which is released with stock(ish) android OS (no skins etc..) The current device in this line is the [Galaxy Nexus which is being sold directly through the (former) Android Market](https://play.google.com/store/devices/details?id=galaxy_nexus_hspa&feature=corpus_selector) That is a good choice because it is more or less the latest generation of hardware, and the newest OS (these Nexus devices tend to receive their OS updates in a more timely manner than carrier tied devices). In fact the first Nexus device was marketed heavily toward developers, this line of phones was meant to be used for development.

> Is a tablet PC the type of device I should get?

If you intend to create applications for tablets then yes. If you intend to develop phone applications you should really be testing on a phone.

> Should I get a device with Android 2.3 or 4.0?

Ideally both on different devices. If you must pick one, then it depends on your budget 4.0 is only on the newest devices right now so they are likely going to be more expensive than some of the devices you can find with 2.3. (although $399 for the Galaxy Nexus might be hard to beat in price, even for some of the 2.3 devices for sale)

> In addition to wifi, what else should I look for?

On phones that can be readily purchased in the US your choices are basically boiled down to only a few things. Screen Size (anywhere from tiny to pretty damn big for a phone), HardwareKeyboard(in a few different shapes and sizes), Camera (if you care about it). In general most of the other features are fairly standard (i.e. bluetooth, gps, accelerometer, etc..) The other thing to consider would be "Oomph", despite being called phones what people are carrying around today are small computers. They have CPU, GPU and RAM just the same as PCs. Battery life is the last major divisor, there is a fairly wide range of battery life expectancy (hint, massive screen and multiple cores need lots of battery). However since you don't seem to want to use this device as your phone some of this stuff may not matter as much to you.

> Are there any brands/models I should avoid?

Anything in the list of your first ebay link. In general (in the US) the major phone manufactures are: HTC, Motorola, Sony, LG, Samsung. There are many other devices out there that are nice as well. But these guys are generally the ones consistently pumping out the most used phones. Idealy you should aim for a spread of device's made by different manufacturers. The custom skins and addons they like to use in their versions of the OS tend to like extra testing. Having one of each will help you help the largest chunk of your users.

> Is there any point in buying used?

There are good deals to be had on nice but slightly dated phones. If you don't know what you are looking at I'd stay away though, it could be easy to get ripped off.

Answer (score 1):

Well it does not seem like you need a very expensive device. Guess you could buy Google's and Samsung's old Nexus S which is not the newest around but still has android 4 because it's Google's "offcial" or something. And since it rolled out with 2.3, you should be able to download the old version somewhere and flash it. That phone should be cheaper, especially second-hand.

I mean since there are so many devices with different screen sizes and all you can't really find one that will reveal what other device-users will think of your apps.

Answer (score 1):

1. Carrier options should be a non-issue for development.  You can buy any Android phone for any 
   carrier including unlocked, and that should not affect your development flexibility.
2. Get the lowest version you can have. 2.3 and 2.2 have the most market shares right now. There is no reason to get 4.0, *unless* you are developing *specifically* for Android OS 4.0 and above (meaning that you actually use API that only exist on 4.0 and above and not lower).
3. Your development platform also affects what phone model to use.  If you use Windows, get a phone that comes with Windows drivers.  It'd be a bummer to buy one only to find out that Windows can't detect it.  Mac and Linux do not need drivers, as they are both UNIX based.

Answer (score 0):

You should get a phone. If you don't want to use it you don't have to... but most likely the majority of your users will be on a device. If you want a device that is always up to date and is great for testing I recommend the Galaxy Nexus.

Since most Android phone users are not on the most up to date os version, I prefer testing on a phone with 2.3

Answer (score 0):

If you temporarily need a phone to test your app, Sony Mobile developer program has a phone loaner program in US and Canada where you can borrow a device for up to 30 days. 
http://developer.sonymobile.com/wportal/devworld/phones/borrow-a-phone

/Magnus E
Sony Mobile